# What is the correct type for document.readyState? to solve Error readyState is not of type EventTarget

Tags: typescript

I need to call a function "start()" after the page enters a readyState of 'complete'. This is to make sure all resources are loaded and the page is loaded. The problem is that the type readyState is not recognized in TypeScript as I have written it from the example found https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState.

I tried to change the code 'event.target.readyState' to '(event.target as Document).readyState' which allows transpilation but the start() function is never called.

```
PUTWindow.addEventListener('readystatechange', event=> {
  if (event.target.readyState  === 'interactive') {
    initLoader();
  }
  else if (event.target.readyState === 'complete') {
    let bodyEl: HTMLElement = PUTWindow.document.body;
    start(PUTWindow);
  }
});
```

This results in the following error message pointing to readyState
"Property 'readyState' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.ts(2339)".

Comment: I should note that i am waiting for the content of a new popup window 'PUTWindow' to load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either need to narrow the type of `event.target` to one that has `readyState` or just use `this` for your element:

```
PUTWindow.addEventListener('readystatechange', function(event) {
  if (this.readyState  === 'interactive') {
    initLoader();
  }
});
```

Comment: This is a correct answer, but I'd emphasize that pay attention to use a `function` and not an `arrow function` if you want to access the window using `this`.

Comment: Sorry i should add that PUTWindow is new popup window and i am waiting for its content to load.

Comment: I know, it doesn't matter.

Comment: The solution is not working and I get the following message: Property 'readyState' does not exist on type 'Window'.ts(2339)

Comment: Window itself is ready as soon as you load JS. There is no `window.readyState`. You should do `PUTWindow.document.addEventListener` instead.

Comment: PUTWindow.document.addEventListener has the same problem. When referencing event.target it always does not have (event.target.readyState) in TypeScript because it is of type EventTarget and needs to be cast into a proper type. What is this type? The solution you provided does not solve the issue.

Comment: It does; did you see the `function(event)` and `this.readyState` difference?

Comment: `this` refers to the `document` element, which has `readyState`

Comment: Thanks @ritaj. You are right and your code modified to PUTWindow.document.addEventListener does compile and it seems to be using "(property) Document.readyState: DocumentReadyState". Please note that none of the three states ('complete' or 'loading' or 'interactive') is triggered. Any ideas on why that is?

Comment: No idea what is happening to the poput itself. Not enough information here.

Comment: Thanks @ritaj. I think the problem was that the web page was fully loaded and in a complete readyState before registering the new event listener and therefore never fired. I dont have enough reputation to vote you up. Thanks again.